# How to support height extender on a rail?

Tags: structural-engineering, materials, design, structures, building-design

I've got an 1/8" thick steel rail with 1.5" diameter and 15' in length sitting on two 5/32" thick steel rails with 2.5" diameter and 100" in length 14' apart:

[image]

I want to add a diagonal support for a rope that is supported with **3/32" thick wires**. I started into the initial design, and stopped here because I don't feel I'm heading in the right direction:

[image]

> How can I structurally strengthen a support to a rail with wires to allow 164" of vertical clearance from the rail to the extended end of said support? Giving a total of ~264" of ground-to-end rope length.

If it's not clear, the rope will hang down to the ground from the end of the extending support rail. Also, if it's of any relevance, the three rails in the first image are schematics from the actual existing physical structure that is already welded together and cemented into the ground (18" deep).

This is where I am now:

[image]

Imagining, here, that the two lower triangular shaped supports are rails to be welded and shaped to the curvature of the rails they attach to. The area below and between the main rails are used for gymnastic rings, some hanging ab straps, and a lowered hanging pull up bar. I mention this because the design, as it stands, seems to clutter up the "work area," if you will.

Comment: What will be the loads on the rope? Just self-weight or additional loads? Can the rope always be assumed to be vertical (straight down to the floor) or might it be pulled in different directions?

Comment: Well, my individual weight, and maybe a friend's individual weight. So, say, 250lbs for safety, but that's not including sudden drop tension from a slip.

Comment: Or the weight of the hardware and the weight of the rope.

Comment: You say "The area below and between the main rails are used for gymnastic rings, some hanging ab straps, and a lowered hanging pull up bar." If this is the case, why come up with this whole structure to hang a rope? Why not simply drop the rope from the ceiling (from which I assume all those other things are hanging)?

Comment: @Wasabi - I think those are hanging from the original three-bar arch, shown in the first image? That's how I read it anyway.